# Phonegap application for Android

Tags: android

I am new to phonegap. According to the steps showed in http://www.phonegap.com/start#android link I developed a simple application.  But the problem is if I include the phonegap.0.9.4.js in `<script>` tag the application is aborting.

If I don't use the phonegap script file my application is running properly. Due to this I am unable to use functions of phonegap. Can any one help me? and please provide any link to develop an application using database in phonegap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a detailed tutorial: [Creating an Android “Hello World” Application with PhoneGap](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/creating-an-android-hello-world-application-with-phonegap/)

Following is the correct syntax for including the phonegap.0.9.4.js in the `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.0.9.4.js"></script>
```

Comment: i used the same syntax...even the sample application also aborting whenever i click on the application.In DDMs of android i m getting VM aborting message

Comment: have you kept the JS file under assets/www ? This sample app works perfectly well for me. What version of API are you using?

Comment: Maybe you should try using a lower level of API. I tested it on android 2.1 (API level 7).

Comment: Can we test the project with lower level API if we have heigher level API or do i need to install android 2.1 ??? Now i have android 2.3.3 (API level 10)

Comment: You can create a new project on your existing environment & select the target API as **2.1**

Comment: thank u...VM aborting problem is resolved.I tried with android 2.2 API level 8..Sample project worked correctly..Can you please provide me any link to debelop an application using Database in phonegap.

Comment: @K.Himabindu If you've got the solution to your problem then kindly consider clicking on the green tick mark near the answer so that your question will be marked as "solved"... Regarding _"Database in phonegap"_ please post that as a new question...thank you